# How to get document after set method in firestore while updating

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am making an update to my document. I use the set method because I want to overwrite my fields. Therefore, when i do my set, it works perfectly, modifying the object in the firestore database. But i am not able to return the document afterward. The error I get:

```
Cannot read property 'exists' of undefined
    at Firebase.js:127
```

Here is my code:

```
const updateItemFromCollection = async (collectionName, uid, data) => {
  return database
    .collection(collectionName)
    .doc(uid)
    .set(data, { merge: true })
    .then(doc => {
      if (!doc.exists) {
        console.log("No such document!"); //Error
      } else {
        return doc.data();
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the [`set()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#set) method returns a `Promise<void>` and not a [`Promise<DocumentSnapshot<T>>`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot).

You will need to read the document again, as follows:

```
const updateItemFromCollection = async (collectionName, uid, data) => {

  const docRef = database.collection(collectionName).doc(uid);

  return docRef.set(data, { merge: true })
    .then(() => {
        return docRef.get();
    .then(doc => {
      if (!doc.exists) {
        console.log("No such document!"); //Error
      } else {
        return doc.data();
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
};
```

---

This is the way Firestore works, and AFAIK, it is based on the fact that you already know the value of the document fields, since you passed a corresponding object to `set()`. One could remark however that this is not true for the values calculated in the back-end based on sentinel values, see [FieldValue](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue).

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i did, simply used the data already passed.

Comment: Well yea but what if you are using set with merge to add partial data, would be nice to get the document back with all fields. Or be able to get the document Id on creation.